# Issue with reading files in C

Tags: c

I have written a program to scan numbers from a file line wise, and find the number of occurrences of each number. It works, but only upto 33 lines. If my text file has 34 lines and above, it does not respond. May I know what is the issue, and what needs to be done? 
Here is the code:`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int numOfDig(int);
int numOfLines(FILE*);
main()
{
  FILE *fp;  
  char ch;
  int c,i,flag=1,line=1,numLine;
  int arr[101];
  for(i=1;i<101;i++)
  {
    arr[i]=0;
  }  
  fp = fopen("new1.txt","r");
  numLine=numOfLines(fp);     
  fclose(fp);
  fp=fopen("new1.txt","r");
  while(line<=numLine)
  {
   ch=fgetc(fp);
    while((ch=fgetc(fp)!=10))
  {           
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);      
    (arr[i])++;    
    c=numOfDig(i);    
      fseek(fp,c-2,SEEK_CUR);        
  }
  line++;  
  }  
  fclose(fp);  
  for(i=1;i<101;i++)
  {
    if(arr[i]!=0)
      printf("%d = %d\n",i,arr[i]);  
  }  
  getch();
}

int numOfDig(int num)
{
  int n=0;
  for(n=0;num>0;num/=10)
    n++;   
  return(n);
}

int numOfLines(FILE *fp)
{
  int numLines=0;
  char ch;
  do 
  {``
    ch = fgetc(fp);
    if(ch == '\n')
      numLines++;
  } while (ch != EOF);
  printf("%d ",numLines);
  return (numLines);      
}
```

Comment: A good practice: always check for the success of `fopen()` before accessing the returned pointer.

Comment: you're looking for newline chars. if the last line DOESN'T end with a newline, you'll completely ignore it.

Comment: You might like to try to debug this yourself: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Also it's `int main(void)` at least.

Comment: Llso, what do you mean by `does not respond`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Also^2: Is there any reason you skip the array's 1st element here: `for(i=1;i<101;i++)`?

Comment: Also^3: This statement `(arr[i])++;` seem to access `arr` out of bounds.

Comment: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`. If your file contains a 0xFF, you will stop, even if the file is longer.

Comment: By does not respond, I mean, it goes into an infinite loop

Comment: PLEASE indent your code.  It is hard to read, and gives people headaches who try to.  Then run it through a debugger like `gdb`

Answer (score 1):

Along with other logical issues [already pointed out in other answer and comments], what I can see, in your code

```
(arr[i])++;
```

`arr[i]` points to invalid memory location, as the value of `i` is not being reset after coming out of `for` loop. So, essentially you're accessing out-of-bound memory and facing *off-by-one* error. This will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Notes:

- in `for(i=1;i<101;i++)`, looping should start from `0`, as C arrays have a starting index of `0`.
- always check for the success of `fopen()` before accessing the returned pointer.

Comment: but why is it that it works for 33 lines, and suddenly, when I increase the line and again run the program, it goes into an infinite loop. :/

Comment: i started it from 1, because i wanted to increase the respective values of the indices :)

Comment: @Aneesh I'm not saying that's the _only_ problem you have in your code, but once an undefined behaviour, always an undefined behaviour. You cannot justify _any_ output of a code showing undefined behaviour.

Comment: I see. So, what do you suggest I do? How do I rectify it?

Comment: @Aneesh control the value of `i` while using `(arr[i])++;` . the condition should be _0 <= i < 101_.

Comment: Besides, why is it running into an infinite loop for 34 and above number of lines?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the EOF issue pointed out, I'll examine a 4-line section of the code line by line. In the first line `fscanf()` sets `i` to a number read from the file as text.

```
fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);
```

In the next line, you haven't tested the value of `i` and if `i < 0` or `i > 100` it will break the array.

```
(arr[i])++;
```

This next line establishes how many digits there were in the number.

```
c=numOfDig(i);
```

Suppose the file contains the sequence "a0". You then resposition the file pointer, but if the number of digits `c == 0`, you will get an infinite loop, because the file pointer will rewind by 2 and re-read the same sequence.

```
fseek(fp,c-2,SEEK_CUR);
```

This is because your function `numOfDig()` is incorrect. When passed `0` it returns `0` instead of `1`.

Comment: There is no scope for the number of digits to be zero, because, i have used rand() to generate the numbers in the text file and taken care that zero is not entered. And all the numbers are only between 1 and 100 for the same reason .

Comment: If a line *starts with* "100", the "1" and the first "0" are read by two `fgetc()` calls and the next "0" by `fscanf()` and the fault I mention will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the logic. You just count `'\n'` symbol, but last line in the file has not this one in the end. Change condition to `if(ch == '\n' || ch == EOF) numLines++;`

Comment: Then it shouldn't be working for 33 lines either, right?

Comment: I think so. Logic OR ( || operator ) just widen condition

Comment: Also change `char ch;` --> `int ch;`